# How can I repair this duplicate key?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

**PrestaShop version 1.6.0.14**

**PHP version 5.5.25**

**MySQL version 5.5.34-cll-lve**

**MySQL engine InnoDB**

[image: database structure]

I recently upgraded Prestashop to the latest version but then realized shortly after that it wasn't compatible with my theme. So, I used my hosts 'server rewind' feature from the cPanel as I forgot to back up the database leaving me with just backup versions of my Public_HTML directory.

Now, when I'm trying to create a product's combinations either manually or with the combination generator, I get this error.

> Duplicate entry '0-1-1' for key 'id_product'

I had checked the database but the that record doesn't exist so I tried the following:

- Repair table
- Optimize table
- DROP table and then re-imported it
- Created new attributes and a new product to test with
- It won't allow me to delete the `id_product` table

Neither of those solutions work... How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the `id_product` had the `UNIQUE` key assigned to it. I had to remove this and now it inserts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me in Prestashop. I tried to import some items and I got this error:

> Error tabla image_shop Duplicate entry '0-1-1' for key 'id_product'

Finally I changed this table: ps_image_shop

```
1   id_product  int(10)         No  Ninguna AUTO_INCREMENT
```

And it works!